# Linq Count method and Performance

Tags: linq

I am using Linq extensively in my project, so far performance is good, i have just one doubt if i have used Linq something like this

```
var getData = objData.where(obj => obj.isDelete ==false)
if (getData != null && getData.Count() > 0)
   foreach(xyz as obj in getdata.ToList())
   {
      //some operation
   }
```

Does getData.Count() and getdata.ToList() performs two different fetches on object? Or as per deffer loading concept when getData.Count() is executed then no operation is performed for .ToList.

If not then should i remove Count condition, will it improve the performance?

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0 acessor methods to get data from DB
List lstpack = new List();

```
            var accessor = _sqlDatabase.CreateSprocAccessor<PackageForClient>("PackageForClientApp", MapBuilder<PackageForClient>
                      .MapAllProperties()
                      .Build()
               );

            var Data = accessor.Execute(startdate, enddate,beinh);
            if (Data != null) //&& Data.Count() > 0 //This has been removed as it is doing an extra fetch
                lstpack = Data.ToList<PackageForClient>();
```

Now returning the list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure, as we don't know what `getData` is, but:

- Yes, potentially they'll be completely separate operations
- In general, use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`; it can be a lot more efficient, particularly in LINQ to Objects
- Calling `ToList` is going to be relatively cheap when it's empty - just do it *if* you need a list
- If you don't *really* need it in a list, just iterate anyway (if there's no data, you'll never get into the loop body)
- `Where` will never return null

In other words, I'd probably write:

```
foreach (Obj xyz in objData.Where(obj => !obj.isDelete))
{
   //some operation
}
```

Comment: Great!! thanks, here getData is list of objects return by result set of Enterprise Library 5.0 , amazed to see that it executes Stored Procedure twice, one when we call Count method of getData and another one when ToList is being used.

Comment: @Deepesh: Why are you amazed to see that? `getData` isn't a list of objects - it's a *query*. Calling `ToList` is what turns it into a list of objects.

Comment: Yes it will but i am surprised to see that Database operations are being performed twice, one for Count and another for List. Means Stored Procedure is executed twice, ideally when Count is being executed then result set should come into memory and not to be executed again when ToList() is called

Comment: @Deepesh: If you want to bring all the results into memory, that's precisely what `ToList` is for. *Some* LINQ providers will cache query results within a context, but it will depend on the details of the provider in question.

Comment: Thank a lot @Jon for helping me in this and clearing my doubts over this. Thanks once again